# Model remapping and Linq2SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, model, lambda

I'm trying my best to try to create a model mapper that passes through any expressions straight back to SQL through Linq2SQL, so far I've managed to remap all properties in the expression tree back to the original model.  The problem I'm getting is that whenever I try and use the expression tree with Linq2SQL it fails with this error:

"The parameter 'modelParamName' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression."

My code is below (for the expression re-mapper - I do have quite a few extension functions within it):

```
// Converting all members from using TModel to TElement
internal class ExpressionModifier<TModel, TElement> : ExpressionVisitor {

    #region Members

    #region Constructors

    internal ExpressionModifier(IQueryable source) { this.source = source; }

    #endregion

    #region Variables

    private IQueryable source;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    internal Expression Modify(Expression expression) { var result = this.Visit(expression); return result; }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) {
        if(node.Type == typeof(TModel)) { return Expression.Parameter(typeof(TElement), node.Name); }
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node) {
        if(node.Value is IQueryable) { return Expression.Constant(this.source); }
        return base.VisitConstant(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) {
        var arguments = node.Arguments.Select(arg => this.Visit(arg));
        var genericTypes = node.Method.GetGenericArguments().Select(arg=>this.VisitParameter(Expression.Parameter(arg)).Type);
        var newMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().SingleOrDefault(method => method.MetadataToken == node.Method.MetadataToken);
        return Expression.Call(newMethod.MakeGenericMethod(genericTypes.ToArray()), arguments);         
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node) {
        var body = this.Visit(node.Body);
        var parameters = node.Parameters.Select(parameter => this.VisitParameter(parameter) as ParameterExpression);
        return Expression.Lambda(body, parameters.ToArray());
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node) {
        var memberName = node.Member.Name;
        var modelAttribute = node.Member.GetAllAttributes().OfType<ModelAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
        if(modelAttribute != null && modelAttribute.Name.IsNotNull()) { memberName = modelAttribute.Name; }
        var newMember = typeof(TElement).GetAllProperties().SingleOrDefault(property => property.Name == memberName);
        if(newMember != null) { return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Visit(node.Expression), newMember); }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion

}
```

Any help identifying what I could be doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what was wrong; but it was not what I expected.  After using process of elimination on a query that could be passed through 'as is', I removed all the visit methods.  This worked, however, the expression was *exactly* the same with all my visit methods but when added back the query didn't work.

It finally found that it stopped working after I added back the VisitParameter method.  After some time, I realised that creating a new ParameterExpression instance from Expression.Parameter, even with the same name, was the issue - if it came up more than once within a related expression block (or scope more specifically).  Even if it had the same name, it technically represented a different parameter altogether when instantiated.

For example:

```
param => param + 1
```

If you use Expression.Parameter(node, "param") twice here, each instance are different variables entirely.  Is this by design?  Surely a parameter with the same type and name in an expression tree (within the same scope) must be the same variable?

The only way I got around this issue was to create a dictionary with types string and ParameterExpression, so if the same named parameter came up again I'd use the previously created instance of the parameter.

I now just have to work out how to keep the parameters in this dictionary applicable only to their own scopes - ah well, I probably get bored if it was too easy.